# Trouble running servlet application in Intellij Community Edition with tomcat server 8.5

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, tomcat8

```
// web.xml    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
             version="3.1">

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.rippleworks.WelcomeServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

// WelcomeServlet.java

```
package com.rippleworks;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        super.doGet(req, resp);
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(resp.getOutputStream());
        out.println("Hello students!");
    }
}
```

// index.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HEllo world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I have configured Intellij to use my local tomcat installation. When i deploy my project, only index.jsp seem to work. An http request to /welcome  path gives 405. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: When you access your JSP do you have to use a context?  That is, usually you would go to a url like `http://localhost:8080/something/` where `something` is the web application context.  You'll need to go to that same context with the servlet - i.e. `http://localhost:8080/something/welcome`.  And have you considered using annotations?  You don't even need web.xml in that case.

Comment: Isn't that configurable in intellij. I've set my application root to /.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the super.doGet(..) that causes the problem. From the source code for
HttpServlet, the default implementation is this,

```
public void doGet(..) {
        String protocol = req.getProtocol();
        String msg = lStrings.getString("http.method_get_not_supported");
        if (protocol.endsWith("1.1")) {
            resp.sendError(405, msg);
        } else {
            resp.sendError(400, msg);
        }
}
```

It'll respond with an error always. Removed the call to super method and it works fine now.

PS. Thanks everyone for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

The servlet mapping seems wrong.. Do something like this:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.rippleworks.WelcomeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WelcomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And your servlet:

```
public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    //do whatever you want here


    //forward request to index
    RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");    
    rd.forward(req,resp);  

    }
}
```

Try that and let me know if it works for you. Remember to restart your server before trying.